# Keras input shape ValueError

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano, keras

I have a problem and at the same time a question. I want to make an image classifier with Keras using Theano as Backend and a Sequential model.

```
>>> keras.__version__
'2.0.1'  
>>> theano.__version__
'0.9.0'
```

My input shape: `INPUT_SHAPE = (3, 28, 28) #depth, size, size`

Let's come to my problem. If I run my script at Windows 7 32 Bit, it gives me the error below out:

```
ValueError: ('The specified size contains a dimension with value <= 0', (-1024, 512))
```

If run it with the the input shape: `INPUT_SHAPE = (28, 28, 3) #size, size, depth`
It gives me out this error below:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (None, 48, 48, 3) but got array with shape (1000, 3, 48, 48)
```

If I run the code on Elementary OS 64 Bit, it runs without any problems (`INPUT_SHAPE = (3, 28, 28)`).

My keras.json file for windows is:

```
{
  "backend": "theano",
  "epsilon": 1e-07,
  "floatx": "float32",
  "image_dim_ordering": "tf"
}
```

So, my question is: Is there such a big difference between different Operating Systems or where is my mistake? Just to remind, I used exactly the same code for both systems.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your problem is not solved yet try using:

`from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')`

This would work good if you wish to use theano backend and have to use channels first configuration for image dimension ordering.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are having has to do with the expected dimension ordering.

- Tensorflow ordering (tf):  Shapes are expected to be (size_lines,size_columns,**channel**)
- Theano ordering (th):  Shapes are expected to be (**channel**,size_lines,size_columns)

If you change the ordering line in the keras.json file to **"image_dim_ordering": "th"** it should work. (i'd bet that's what's in your Elementary OS keras.json).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for my late response. You're still right, but I recognized that my .keras file doesn't change anything. I installed keras without any envs and one time trought anaconda. After setting the image_data_format to 'channels_first' in my code it works without any issues. So it was totally my fault. :D But thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

For switching to another backend you can change the configuration file located in:

- Linux: `$HOME/.keras/keras.json`
- Windows: `%USER_PROFILE%/.keras/keras.json`

This is the `keras.json` file for `theano` backend:

```
{
    "floatx": "float32",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "backend": "theano",
    "image_data_format": "channels_first"
}
```

This is the `keras.json` file for `tensorflow` backend:

```
{
    "floatx": "float32",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "backend": "tensorflow",
    "image_data_format": "channels_last"
}
```

This is what the documentation https://keras.io/backend/ says about the `image_data_format` property:

> `image_data_format`: `string`, either `"channels_last"` or `"channels_first"`. 
>   It specifies which data format convention Keras will follow.
>   (`keras.backend.image_data_format()` returns it.)
>
> For 2D data (e.g.
>   image), `"channels_last"` assumes `(rows, cols, channels)` while
>   "channels_first" assumes `(channels, rows, cols)`.
>
> For 3D data,
>   `"channels_last"` assumes `(conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3, channels)`
>   while `"channels_first"` assumes `(channels, conv_dim1, conv_dim2, conv_dim3)`.